# Anisotropic refractive index with isotropic components?

Tags: solid-state-physics, refraction, biophysics, crystals

In relation to my question [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10945/isotropicity-of-sarcomere-bands-in-skeletal-muscle-cells) I wanted to make sure that my physical argument was not flawed.

Anisotropic properties, (especially refractive index) is characteristic of a well-ordered solid (usually crystalline). On the other hand Isotropic properties is indicative of an amorphous solid, i.e lack of well-ordered arrangement (a random arrangement). The question is:-

> **Can any composite arrangement of isotropic elements give an
>   anisotropic system? Can any arrangement of anisotropic elements give an isotropic system?**

Intuitively, I think, it should not be possible, if isotropicity implies random arrangement (of individually anisotropic components) since any arrangement of random elements should not give a well-ordered system capable of exhibiting anisotropic refractive index.

As for the other part of my question, intuitively, it must be possible, since a random arrangement of anisotropic elements will impart an overall randomness and hence isotropic refractive index. (If I am not mistaken, this is what happens in short-range order amorphous solids, whre individually anisotropic grains are randomly arranged to produce an isotropic solid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right, a macroscopic anisotropy is the result of a microscopic ordering of some type of the constituent. Even a free electron gas (or a plasma) can show anisotropic optical properties when subject to an external magnetic field. When you talk about composite arrangement of isotropic elements though, you're are talking about macroscopic subparts of your system, you can't say that a molecule is isotropic.

In this sense, the most simple composition of macroscopic isotropic objects which results in an anisotropic one is the following: take two isotropic pieces of solids with different optical properties and create a junction between them. The direction normal to the junction is a preferential direction, therefore the junction constitutes a local anisotropy in the system of the combined solids.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A minor clarification, is this valid for properties other than refractive index (coefficient of thermal expansion, elastic constants,etc)?

Comment: Mhm, I'm quite sure that for the elastic constant is the same. If you think about it, the elastic stress tensor is the correspondent of the Maxwell stress tensor in electromagnetism. For the thermal expansion I don't quite know, the equations are parabolic, they have different boundary conditions that may lead to different reflection/refraction conditions